# Values returns a blank whereas I don't have one?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, measure

_Hi, I can't understand why my "Values" measure returns a blank whereas I don't have any in my table ? Thanks for your help.

```
       Values = COUNTROWS( VALUES( 'Plans Comptages'[N° CPT] ) )
       DistinctCount = DISTINCTCOUNT( 'Plans Comptages'[N° CPT] )
```

[Here is the link of my Pbix file](https://1drv.ms/u/s!An2aQoxg76Kv8GLXZX5OzoR-wFO8?e=d5crdG)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VALUES() returns the blank row for entries in your fact table which do not exist in your dimension table. DISTINCT() does not return the blank row.

It's a good way to spot invalid relationships and referential integrity issues. Your final report should have no blank rows if you've modelled everything correctly.

Further reading: https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/blank-row-in-dax/

Comment: Thanks ! In other words, the 1 blank row points out all the datas that does not exist in the dimension table ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. If you open DAX studio, you can see the invalid relationships highlighted in a table. You can also place keys from both tables in a table visual to see where there are missing items or do an anti join in Power Query. A good model will have an entry in the dimension table for all rows in the fact table and is a sign that someone has modelled the data correctly.